# how to resize images in a html mailer to support smart phone and pc?

Tags: html, css

i have an image header for a **HTML-mailer** with the width of 600px and height of 75px. is there a way to reduce the size of the image when the mail is read on a smart phone? Can i use in line css `max-width:600px; width:100%;` so that the maximum width stays at 600px and then when viewed on a smart phone with smaller screen size it shrinks to the phone display size? or will it create any problems?

Answer (score 0):

Using absolute pixel values is usually a bad idea. Try creating a "fluid layout" that looks good in almost all sizes.

To change CSS depending on the available display size, try "css media queries".

Your solution (`max-width`) should work as well, just test and try, it should work.